# Jira registration of webhook via REST API

Tags: web, jira, webhooks, jira-rest-api

I've looked through every similar topic here in the forums, and couldn't really find anything that would help me.

I've built 3LO integration with my product, and trying to add webhooks via rest API. The first Hook is created successfully, how ever if I tried to create another hook for another user on the same App I get this message.

```
"webhookRegistrationResult": [
    {
        "errors": [
            "Only a single URL per app is allowed to be registered via REST API. Currently used URL: https://example.com/api/webhooks/jira"

        ]
    }
]
```

and my request is:

```
POST https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/{cloud-Id}/rest/api/3/webhook

{
    "url": "https://example.com/api/webhooks/jira",
    "webhooks": [
        {
            "jqlFilter": "status = Done or status != Done",
            "events": [
                "comment_created",
                "comment_updated",
                "jira:issue_created",
                "jira:issue_updated"

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create a webhook for each user associated with my App to get any updates in issues or comments related to this user.